# Trying to get mouse controls to work in JQuery using .on(click)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add mouse controls for navigation to my game. I have created some buttons on the screen as shown below:

```
<input type="image" id= "buttonUp" src="UpButton.jpg" alt="Up" style="position:absolute; left: 200px; top: 550px;">
<input type="image" id= "buttonDown" src="DownButton.jpg" alt="Down" style="position:absolute; left: 200px; top: 650px;">
<input type="image" id= "buttonLeft" src="LeftButton.jpg" alt="Left" style="position:absolute; left: 100px; top: 650px;">
<input type="image" id= "buttonRight" src="RightButton.jpg" alt="Right" style="position:absolute; left: 300px; top: 650px;">
```

Each one obviously corresponds to each direction of movement. And then from there I'm trying to have them trigger when clicked:

```
$('.buttonUp').on('click', function () {
  direction == "up";
});
$('.buttonDown').on('click', function () {
  direction == "down";
});     
$('.buttonLeft').on('click', function () {
  direction == "left";
});     
$('.buttonRight').on('click', function () {
  direction == "right";
});
```

But it doesn't do anything when clicked. How can I fix this?

Comment: Firstly you're using class selectors when your elements have ids. Change the `.` to `#`. Then you need to use `=` to set a variable. `==` is for checking equality. However, even with just setting a variable, what are you expecting it to do? Your code doesn't appear to be doing anything else.

Comment: You're assigning the event by `class`, but the input elements doesn't have any. You should be doing by ID, like `$('#buttonUp')`.

Comment: And you're using comparisons to set the value. Never gonna work. Use = rather than ==

Comment: @JonRogerson, read the comments and answers. We have told you what's wrong already.

Comment: Oh I got it working, it was a combination of using . rather than "#" and having 2 "=" signs, thank you for your help. I am now going to try to get it to work for touch controls with touchstart, any advice before I go into it?

Comment: You've also got a space after the `id=`, which isn't supposed to be there. You say it works for you now, and I believe you, but it's incorrect HTML and I wouldn't be surprised if it failed on some other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

In order to assing values to variables you have to use one `equals` symbol, not two like you are doing it in your code that's for comparing values. Change all of your `==` to just `=`.

Also you are using class selectors `.` but you should be using id selectors `#`

Answer (score 1):

Now, you are duplicating code all sorts of ways. You're using a class selector to get an element by id. And you're using an equality comparison to try to set value. Instead, I've got a single fuction that connects to all the controls, and uses the alt value of the control to set direction. See below.

```js
var direction;
$('.control-btn').on('click', function ()
    {
        direction = $(this).attr("alt").toLowerCase();
        console.log(direction);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="image" id= "buttonUp" class="control-btn" src="UpButton.jpg" alt="Up" style="position:absolute; left: 200px; top: 50px;">
    <input type="image" id= "buttonDown" class="control-btn" src="DownButton.jpg" alt="Down" style="position:absolute; left: 200px; top: 150px;">
    <input type="image" id= "buttonLeft" class="control-btn" src="LeftButton.jpg" alt="Left" style="position:absolute; left: 100px; top: 150px;">
    <input type="image" id= "buttonRight" class="control-btn" src="RightButton.jpg" alt="Right" style="position:absolute; left: 300px; top: 150px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your direction logic is already coded, you have to change `==` to `=`. `==` is for comparison. Use `=` for equating values to `direction`.

Moreover, you are using ID in HTML code but targeting class selector in script.